# Extract ADLS gen2 details

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-data-lake-gen2

How to get adls gen2 details. I want path along with size in kb recursively. I was tring with the below code but it is showing only size of all the folder not even shoing the path.

```
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "******" -UseConnectedAccount

$Files = Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem -Context $ctx -FileSystem "******" -Path "a/b/c" -Recurse 

$Total = $Files | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
$Total | Select-Object @{Name="Path";E={$Path}},@{Name = "SizeInKB"; Expression={$_.Sum/1KB}}
```

My desire output is

```
Path    SizeInKB
a/b/c           0
a/b/c/ef       10
..........  ......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an **ADLS Gen2 storage account** and created a file system like below:

[image]

Under the file system, **I created directories, sub directories and uploaded test files**:

[image]

To **fetch the path and the size in kb**, modify the PowerShell script like below:

```bash
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "xxx" -UseConnectedAccount  
$Path = "testdirectory/subdirectory"

$Files = Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem -Context $ctx -FileSystem "filesystem1" -Path $Path -Recurse
  
$Total = $Files | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum  
$Total | Select-Object @{Name="Path";E={$Path}},@{Name = "SizeInKB"; Expression={$_.Sum/1KB}}
```

[image]

To **fetch the path and the size in kb for multiple paths**, try the below code:

```bash
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "xxx" -UseConnectedAccount  
$Paths = @("testdirectory/subdirectory", "test/testsub1")

foreach ($Path in $Paths) {  
$Files = Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem -Context $ctx -FileSystem "filesystem1" -Path $Path -Recurse  

$Total = $Files | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum  
$Total | Select-Object @{Name="Path";E={$Path}},@{Name = "SizeInKB"; Expression={$_.Sum/1KB}}  
}
```

[image]